# for statement loop not working as expected

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, count, nsmutablearray

I do no understand why this for loop will not loop! Any help appreciated. For some reason the i++ is not working??

The busTypeForSectionsFirst contains an array of multiple letters, i.e. A through to Z. (Different amounts of each letter)

The tempArray is an array of just A through to Z.

My log looks like this: x26 times.

> 2013-01-08 11:17:53.596 App[969:c07] i = 0
>
> 2013-01-08 11:17:53.596 App[969:c07] Count of i in array = 2
>
> 2013-01-08 11:17:53.596 App[969:c07] Object searched - A

```
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:busTypeForSectionsFirst];

NSLog(@"%@", countedSet);

for (int i=0; i<=26; i++) {
    if (![countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]]) {
        NSLog(@"Nil");
        NSLog(@"i = %i", i);
        NSLog(@"Count of i in array = %i", [countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]]);
        NSLog(@"Object searched - %@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        return 0;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"i = %i", i);
        NSLog(@"Count of i in array = %i", [countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]]);
        NSLog(@"Object searched - %@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        return 0;
        return [countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }}

return 0;
```

Comment: If you are adding return statement in both if and else, it will return in first iteration itself right? Why do you expect it to loop then? and this will never get called `return [countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];` since `return 0` is there.

Comment: Yep, `return` statements will exit the loop (and the method/function) altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But you can probably try this code,

```
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:busTypeForSectionsFirst];

NSLog(@"%@", countedSet);

NSInteger returnVal = 0;

for (int i=0; i<=26; i++) {
    if (![countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]]) {
        NSLog(@"Nil");
        NSLog(@"i = %i", i);
        NSLog(@"Count of i in array = %i", [countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]]);
        NSLog(@"Object searched - %@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"i = %i", i);
        NSLog(@"Count of i in array = %i", [countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]]);
        NSLog(@"Object searched - %@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        returnVal = [countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        //break; //probably a break statement here is what you are looking for
    }
}

return returnVal;
```

If you put a return statement in the loop it will exit there and return from the method. In your case, you are trying to return in both `if` and `else` condition which will cause the `for` loop to execute only once. And your `return [countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];` will never get executed since you are adding a `return 0;` before that.

If you want to break a for loop, you need to use `break;` statement. `return` will return from the method and will not execute rest of the code below that.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was the double up of the returning that broke the for loop :-)

Answer (score 0):

It won't loop because in both the true and false parts of the `if` statement, *you return from the function!*

I suspect the `return 0` statement may be superfluous, due to this little beauty:

```
return 0;
return [countedSet countForObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

which will only *ever* return `0` - the second `return` being unreachable code.

However, I can't be certain of that based on the information given. My comment still stands though - the loop will only ever iterate once due to the `return` statements in all code paths.

Answer (score 0):

A classical copy and paste error! one of the `return 0` has to be removed. Guess which one!

Comment: I seen that after I posted and removed it, still broken though :-)